# How to animate range input element properly?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I have an HTML range input element (slider) whose value I update dynamically using JavaScript. This works fine until I click on the slider, at which point it's no longer updated. Is this a bug in Firefox or why is this happening?

```
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
<script>
var timeValue = 0;
var timeSlider = d3.select("body").append("input")
.attr("type", "range")
.attr("min", 0)
.attr("max", 10000)
.style("width", "500px");

window.setInterval(update, 20);

function update() {
    timeValue += 20;
    timeSlider.attr("value", timeValue);
}
</script>
```

Comment: can you post a snippet of your code to illustrate the functionality?

Comment: This is works in other browsers?

Comment: No, even worse in Chrome. Maybe sliders are not supposed to be animated.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience when you are animating an input control, and the user does anything that results in the control being focused, the animation halts or misbehaves due to the browser is going to make sure the input control is located where it can be seen by the user, which often is not exactly where you want. This is not exclusive of FF I'be experienced similar problems in Chrome and IE.

To solve this problem you must disable the input control before the animation starts and enable it again after the animation ends.